# It's more trouble than ... Is it an abbreviation of "of"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives, abstract-nouns

It's more trouble than it's worth.

If these sentences have the same structure as "he is a doctor," then "it = trouble" should work.
However, in practice, I think it means 'it is not worth the trouble', which implies 'the work has more trouble than the worth'.

So, If "It" is "the task", then I don't think "the task = more trouble."(I think that the correct is the task is troublesome.)
"troublesome" is an adjective.

I guessed that "of" is omitted in this sentence. If that is correct, I think that the original sentence is "it is (of) more trouble than ...".

e.g.) of great interest = greatly interesting ※"of" + adjective + abstract noun = adverb(from adjective) + adjective(from noun)

What do you think? Is my guess correct?

meaning　(from Cambridge Dictionary/ Collins Dictionary)

trouble: slight problems or effort (noun)

troublesome:giving trouble or anxiety / difficult (adjective)

more trouble than : it is not important or useful enough to make an effort doing it

Example ("of" + adjective +"trouble")
The report is of “great trouble and shame. (IBC BREMEN)

ONE FEMALE PRISONER IS OF MORE TROUBLE THAN TWENTY MALES. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3789896

it is of much trouble to clean such medical soil reservoirs. CN201019954Y - Mobile toilet seat for bone fracture patient - Google Patents

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, No.

*It's more trouble than it's worth* can be rendered perfectly naturally as *It is more trouble than it is worth*: there is no "of" involved.

This use of "trouble" (uncountable, meaning "effort" or "bother") is relatively uncommon, but it occurs in some other common expressions:

> If it's not too much trouble ...

> No, it's no trouble!

> If you take the trouble to ...

> They went to some trouble to ...

Of the examples you quote, the first is a different construction (*a report of*, not *of trouble*), and the others are not idiomatic English, and are either mistakes, or written by non-native English speakers. *It is of much trouble* is doubly deviant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.　Is this the same for "It's more headache than it's worth."?

Comment: That is not idiomatic, because when we use _headache_ in this sense it is countable; so we might say _It's more of a headache than it's worth_. The _of_ is required because _more a headache_ has a different meaning that will not fit in that context.

Comment: OK.  When we use "more a headache", what is the meaning of the sentence ?　Does the "headache" in "more a headache" means a pain of a head?

Comment: If you use _more a headache_ the sentence is nonsense. The only way to use that phrase is something like _This is more a headache than a benefit_, with the parallellism between _a headache_ and _a benefit_. In some circumstances this might mean roughly the same as the previous sentence, but it only makes sense if there is an expectation (or statement) that whatever it is is a benefit.

Comment: Thank you! 　Is the following understanding correct?
Examples where "of" can be omitted in combination with the indefinite article + countable noun (a headache), as in "more a headache than" ⇒ 
"B" in "than it's B" has similarity to headache as in "than it's benefit" and there is an expectation that whatever it is is a benefit.    
　Usually, "more of an A than B" is used, as in "more of a headache than it's worth". In this case, the expectation that whatever it is is a benefit is not implied, so it can be used in any case.　(1/2)

Comment: "More trouble than it's worth" does not include of because trouble is an uncountable noun and has no article.　　"more of a headache than it's benefit" and "more a headache than it's benefit" have the same primary meaning, which is "the difficulty of it outweighs it's value."　(2/2)

Comment: I wish I'd never brought up _more a headache_, because it is confusing you (and me). _More trouble_ means "a greater amount of trouble". _More of a headache_ could be used in the same way: "a bigger headache". _More a headache_ is a different construction with a different meaning of _more_: it means "a headache to a greater degree".

Comment: "than it's benefit" is not idiomatic, and I don't know what it would mean. I said _more a headache than a benefit_ (no "it's") meaning "a headache to a greater degree than (the degree to which it is) a benefit".